# bootstrap container width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to change the width of the `container` class so that it's wider?  I want a 3-column fixed-width layout with sizes similar to this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="span3">
      span3
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      span6
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      span3
    </div>
  </div>
```

But the third div doesn't fit in one line.  It gets carried over to the next line so I'm guessing the `container` is too narrow.

mike

Comment: Read carefully the [grid documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and build your grid from scratch, following the doc instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third column isn't fitting as your span elements aren't inside a row div (`<div class="row">`)

The below code (also on http://jsfiddle.net/3yG6j/1/) should fix your problem, and put all the spans on the same row

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
          span3
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          span6
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          span3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No the same thing happens.  The container doesn't expand.  It works fine if I have span2 span6 span2.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out.  I had to do a `container` and a `row-fluid` within it.  But I was wondering could I do something bigger?  Like span3 span7 span3?

Comment: Not by default - Bootstrap supports a 12 wide grid system by default - You can customise this if you download bootstrap using custom variables - see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables
You can also customise the width of each grid column (to make the overall width wider) - Hopefully that will give what you want.

With your current setup with the row it should all fit on one line - can you post a jsfiddle with sample data (of the same length) as I'm interested why it goes onto a second line?